# Confusing datetime objects in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I face some confusion with the way `pandas` is handling time-related objects.

If I do

```
x = pd.datetime.fromtimestamp(1440502703064/1000.) # or
x = pd.datetime(1234,5,6)
```

then `type(x)` returns `datetime.datetime` in either of the cases. However if I have:

```
z = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a': 'foo', 'ts': pd.datetime.fromtimestamp(1440502703064/1000.)}
    ])
```

then `type(z['ts'][0])` returns `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`. When is this casting happening? Is its trigger is `pandas` or maybe `numpy`? What is this type that I obtain in the latter case and where is it documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, since I haven't studied the underlying code, but the conversion from `datetime.datetime` happens the moment the value is "incorporated" into a `DataFrame`.

Outside a `DataFrame`, pandas will try to do the smart thing and return something sensible when using `pd.dattime(.fromtimestamp)`: it returns a Python `datetime.datetime` object.

Inside, it uses something it can probably work better with internally. You can see the conversion occurring when creating a `DataFrame` by using a `datetime.datetime` object instead:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> z = pd.DataFrame([
       {'a': 'foo', 'ts': datetime(2015,8,27)} ])
>>> type(z['ts'][0])
pandas.tslib.Timestamp
```

Perhaps even clearer:

```
>>> pd.datetime == datetime
True
```

So the conversion happens during the `DataFrame` initialisation.

As for documentation, I searched around and found the [source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tslib.pyx#L222) (note: probably not a very time-safe link), which says (doc-string):

> TimeStamp is the pandas equivalent of python's Datetime and is
>   interchangable with it in most cases. It's the type used for the
>   entries that make up a DatetimeIndex, and other timeseries oriented
>   data structures in pandas.

Comment: Sounds good. So `TimeStamp` is sort of an internal undocumented object. Great :(

Comment: well it would help to read the extensive documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dtypes